# allocate const value into specific condition using nested if else statement only

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to allocate certain const value into specific condition.

For instance, I've 3 const value

```
const double highDiscount = 0.3;
const double midDiscount = 0.2;
const double lowDiscount = 0.1;
```

The product with the highest cost should receive the highDiscount while the mid cost should receive the midDiscount and the lowest cost should receive the lowDiscount.

Therefore, i tried using the if-else statement to allocate the const via specific condition.

```
double discount;

if (acost > bcost && acost > ccost)
{

    discount = highDiscount;
    
    if ( bcost < ccost)
    {
        discount = midDiscount;
    
    }
    else if ( ccost < bcost )
    {
        discount = lowDiscount;
    }
}
```

Using my output codes

```
cout << "acost has a" discount*100 << "% discount" << endl;
cout << "bcost has a" discount*100 << "% discount" << endl;
cout << "ccost has a" discount*100 << "% discount" << endl;
```

which should produce the results below

> acost has a 30% discount
>
> ccost has a 20% discount
>
> bcost has a 10% discount

Unfortunately, when i compile my codes, it turns out that all a,b and c has the 10% discount instead of the allocated const value.

Am i missing out some key important points here?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Do you have `adiscount` ? How do you call your code ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I've editted my post. and yes, i declare my discount as a double.

Comment: Are you only setting one discount for the entire program or do you have a separate `discount` for each product?

Comment: Not entirely sure if i understand your code correctly, your 3 cout's at the end,  you know that you always print the SAME discount variable right?

Comment: @NathanOliver i do have separate discount. the one with the highest cost should have the most discount while the lowest cost should have the least.

Comment: So you have 3 different variables?  Your code only shows you setting one.

Comment: But in shown code, you have only one.

Comment: @MarioDekena yes. however, the different value of discount differs with the cost of each item. for instance, the highest cost should have the most while the lowest should have the least. That is why i tried using the if else statement to allocate the variable "discount" with different const values.

Comment: Could you elaborate "Item". Show us some more of your program structure.

Comment: @Jarod42 i only have one because i'm trying to allocate a const value of 0.3/0.2/0.1 into the double variable "discount."

Comment: If you only have one and you only set it once then how would if be three different values?  A variable can only have one state at a time.  You are going to need a discount variable for each product.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan I added a fully contained / standalone codesample demonstrating my approach.

Comment: Have you heard of a function...? Or a member variable, or etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In product class, add the < operator

```
bool operator< (const product &other) const {
    return cost < other.cost;
}
```

Then create a vector holding all your products.

```
vector<product> products;
products.push_back(product1);
products.push_back(product2);
products.push_back(product3);
```

Sort your product vector (which will sort by cost)

```
std::sort(products.begin(), products.end());
```

And just apply your discount to the sorted elements

```
products[0].discount = lowDiscount;
products[1].discount = midDiscount;
products[2].discount = highDiscount;
```

This is much easier to read and debug as those nested if statements.

Not entirely sure whats wrong with your code, hard to tell without seeing the complete code.

Edit:
Since there is something fundamentally wrong with your code logic, here is a fully contained sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


class product {
public:
    product(std::string name, double cost);
    ~product();
    //in product class, add the < operator
    bool product::operator< (const product &other) const;
    std::string Name;
    double Cost;
    double Discount;
};

product::product(std::string name, double cost) : Name(name), Cost(cost){}
product::~product(){}


const double highDiscount = 0.3;
const double midDiscount = 0.2;
const double lowDiscount = 0.1;

struct CompareProductPointers {
    bool operator()(const product* l, const product* r) {
        return *l < *r;
    }
};

int main() {
    //create a vector holding all your products
    product product1("product1", 10);
    product product2("product2", 8);
    product product3("product3", 12);

    std::vector<product*> products;
    products.push_back(&product1);
    products.push_back(&product2);
    products.push_back(&product3);

    //sort your product vector (which will sort by cost)
    std::sort(products.begin(), products.end(), CompareProductPointers());

    //apply your discount to the sorted elements
    products[0]->Discount = lowDiscount;
    products[1]->Discount = midDiscount;
    products[2]->Discount = highDiscount;

    //output
    std::cout << product1.Name << " has a " << (product1.Discount * 100) << "% discount" << std::endl;
    std::cout << product2.Name << " has a" << (product2.Discount * 100) << "% discount" << std::endl;
    std::cout << product3.Name << " has a" << (product3.Discount * 100) << "% discount" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether the OP was using a product class at all, and given their expectation that a single `const` variable could somehow apply differently to each product, I would guess they weren't at that stage yet.